# How to install stellard on a server with integrate design?

Tags: stellar.js

I want to install stellard on my server. I download the stellard from github directory, here is [link](https://github.com/stellar/stellard). Now I want to install and implement the design. I want step by step procedure to install like all configuration and database setup, etc. So how can I do this?

**What I already done..**

I am new in this open source and need deep demonstration of its installation and implementation. I also search out google, But can't get any useful tutorial how to work on this. I see there are some commands for installation but I can't way to work. Someone who really experience in stellard can give view to work on stellard. First I want to install stellard on my local host and after that on my live server.

**My review about stellard..**

This is very rare use open source.I search out is solution in some programing sites but can't get any help. Even I search stellard/ripple in youtube but no tutorial available there?

Comment: Did you consult the [stellar for developers](https://www.stellar.org/developers/)?

Comment: I fresh on stellard and background is php.I am able to get their commands.So I need help to installation and design implementation.